# In tmux, arrow and ctrl+arrow both result in the same code

Tags: shell, putty, zsh, tmux

Ubuntu 12.10, TERM is set to screen-256color in putty and tmux.conf, confirmed when I `export` both in and out of a tmux session.

If I run `cat > /dev/null` and then press `<down>` then `<c-down>`, I get `^[[B^[OB` outside of a tmux session, but `^[[B^[[B` while inside a session.

I've tried `setw -g xterm-keys on` in my .tmux.conf to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

`screen-256color` is a valid TERM value for use inside *tmux*, but  `xterm-256color` would probably be more appropriate for outside of *tmux* (where you are “just inside” *PuTTY*). Attaching to a *tmux* session with an inaccurate TERM value is akin to lying to *tmux* about the control sequences your terminal emulator uses (i.e. *PuTTY* probably does not support exactly the control sequences described by the `screen-256color` terminfo database entry).

I do not use *PuTTY*, but searching around a bit left me with the impression that *PuTTY* does not support sending sequences that actually mean (e.g.) <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. The different sequences you observe are actually two different sequences for plain <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. `^[[B` is the normal sequence, and `^[OB` is for when a program has requested “application cursor keys” mode.

So, when *PuTTY* sends `^[OB`, any program expecting `xterm`-style sequences will interpret that sequence as “<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, while in application cursor keys mode” (or just <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>), but never as <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. Specifically, when *tmux* sees either of those sequences, it interprets it as a plain <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. The sequence that *tmux* then generates for its pane depends on whether that particular pane has been configured for application cursor key mode or not.

In your case, you have not asked *tmux* to switch its pane to application cursor keys mode, so it translated the sequence to its “normal” sequence in both cases. You should be able to observe the difference by running commands like these (either inside or outside a *tmux*) (the *tput* commands generate the control sequences that activate and deactivate the required terminal modes):

```sh
# Activate "Application Cursor Keys" (and "Application Keypad")
tput smkx ; cat
# Press Down Arrow to see '^[OB', then Control-C to kill the cat

# Activate "Normal Cursor Keys" (and "Normal Keypad")
tput rmkx ; cat 
# Press Down Arrow to see '^[[B', then Control-C to kill the cat
```

If you can somehow convince *PuTTY* to send xterm-style modified arrow key sequences (i.e. `^[[1;5B` for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>), then *tmux* will generate the same sequences for its panes when `xterm-keys` is enabled.